# Apple API/SDK: requestUserToken without Swift/Objective-C?

Tags: python, objective-c, swift, apple-music

I need to be able to retrieve user-specific data from Apple Music. After some searching, it seems the moethod to do this is [requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skcloudservicecontroller/2909079-requestusertokenfordevelopertoke):

> Returns a user token that you use to access personalized Apple Music
>   content.

However, the example given there is in Swift or Objective-C. I'm not experienced enough to figure out if this code is "portable" to another language like Python.

Is it possible?

Comment: whats meaning ok `if this code is "portable" to another language like Python.`

Comment: @aircraft I meant to ask: is it possible to acquire a user Token if the user isn’t on iOS? After some research the answer seems to be no.

Comment: apple only provide `swift` and `objective-c` interfaces.

Comment: @aircraft sure. But even if I write it in Swift, on a non-Apple machine, that wouldn’t help, is all I’m asking.

Answer (score -1):

Please be attention:

```
- (void)requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken:(NSString *)developerToken 
                        completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *userToken, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

This is a Objective-C interface, you can also switch language in there(The Language drop-down there shows all the languages):

[image]

Then there will shows the Swift interface now:

```
func requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken developerToken: String, 
    completionHandler: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void)
```

Apple only provide the two language types API for developers, there is **no python（other） language interface** there.

---

From your:

> But even if I write it in Swift, on a non-Apple machine, that wouldn’t help, is all I’m asking.

You check the API doc in the right sidebar, will find:

```
SDKs

iOS 11.0+
tvOS 11.0+

Framework

StoreKit
```

The API is available in iOS and tvOS SDKs, Apple do not run those SDKs on the non-apple machine.